# how to use CLR and JC in assembly?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
     ORG 0100H
INIT:               
        MOV AL,99H
        OUT 06,AL
        MOV AL,0
        OUT 02,AL
        MOV TEMP,01DH
LOOP:   CALL ADC
        CALL HEX2ASC
        CLR C
    SUB AL,TEMP
    JC TEMPLO
    CLR AL
    JMP TEMP1
TEMPLO: MOV AL,20H
TEMP1:  OUT 02,AL
        JMP LOOP
ADC:    IN AL,00
        MOV BL,AL
    IN AL,00
    CLR C
    SUB AL,BL
    JNZ ADC
    MOV AL,BL
    RET
HEX2ASC: PUSH AX
        MOV CL,4
    ROR AL,CL
    CALL DISPLAY
    POP AX
    CALL DISPLAY
    MOV CX,2
BACKSP: PUSH CX
        MOV AL,08
    CALL FPUTC
    POP CX
    DEC CX
    JNZ BACKSP
    RET
DISPLAY: AND AL,0FH
        CMP AL,0AH
    JC DISP1
    ADD AL,7
DISP1   ADD AL,30H
        CALL FPUTC
    RET
FPUTC:  PUSHF 
        PUSH DX 
    PUSH CX 
    PUSH AX
        XOR CX,CX
    MOV ES,CX
    MOV BYTE PTR ES:[01E5],5E
    MOV AH,24
    MOV ES:[01E5+1],AX
    MOV AL,06
    INT 06
    POP AX
    POP CX
    POP DX
    POPF 
    RET A
TEMP:    DS 1
```

I got this code form a book but when I use the code show me error

(10) illegal instruction: CLR C or wrong parameters.

(13) illegal instruction: CLR AL or wrong parameters.

(21) illegal instruction: CLR C or wrong parameters.

(42) undeclared label: JC DISP1

How I can fix these error?

Comment: `CLR C`seems like an 8051 instruction, not an 8086 instruction. What book did you get `CLR C` from?

Comment: Your `DISP1` label is missing a colon

Comment: application board experiment manual flt-8086 book

Comment: Part of me thinks you have combined information from an 8051 kit and an 8086 kit and then tried running code in a different environment `emu8086`. Maybe this is an XY problem. Are you trying to write code to work for EMU8086 or are you trying to write code for a training board?

Comment: no , I don have link to my book

Comment: this code not work in 8086 kit and EMU8086

Comment: It doesn't work because it looks like you are using information from an 8051 kit. Does your book talk about 8051 and 8086? If this is for your course I think you need to talk to a professor or teacher assistant to get you on the right path. It is clear to me here that you are confused. It's hard to help since we do't see your source material. Can tell you that Flight-8086 training board code will not run in emu8086 and `clr c` is an 8051 instruction, not an 8086 instruction. Good luck.

Comment: `CLR C` is an instruction of 8051 Microcontroller and emu8086 is for 8086 processor so this instruction won't work in emu8086. As this instruction is used for clearing carry flag so in emu8086 you can do the same with `CLC` instruction.`CLR` can also be used for clearing register (`CLR A` where 'A' stands for accumulator in 8051) and this can be done in 8086 with `xor` (`xor al, al`) instruction.  As far as `JC` is concerned its used to jump to a specific label if carry flag is set. This instruction is available in 8086. So you can use it in emu8086.

Comment: btw i managed to get rid of all those errors but now it throws different kind of errors. As i can see your code is trying to communicate with I/0.

Comment: You are using emu08086 which emulates an 8086 and typical BIOS/DOS interrupts. It does not emulate your flight board (the interrupts on the flight 8086 are not like a normal PC). You are using the wrong tool here. Why did you choose EMU8086 if you have a flight board? Or do you have a flight board at all? Are you using EMU8086 to generate a binary file and then are you putting it on your flight board? EMU8086 won't run the code the way you expect.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I didn't know about this "flight 8086 board", so I tried to look it up and I found virtually no information - do you have some sources? I got curious about it...

Comment: @MatteoItalia : A couple academia links regarding the board is here: http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/EE/ahussain/teaching/Exp_07.pdf and.http://www.ccse.kfupm.edu.sa/~hazem/coe305/part2-expr01.pdf . Overview and specs of the board: http://www.otdl.com/Fl8086.pdf

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you; I were doubly curious because of the name - after I heard that the A340 FCS used x86 processors for half computers (the other half being m86k) I thought that this board may had something to do with flight systems. A bit far fetched, I know - the board you linked me seems more like a big Arduino from times when micros didn't integrate much besides the CPU.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think the best tool for him would be **Keil Development tool for 8051 Micro-controller** as i have suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Ahtisham Depends on whether he is actually using an 8051 or not. That is still debatable. The tag is EMU8086. Most of the code is 8086 some of it is 8051. The port initialization code at the top (writing 0x99 to port 0x6) is consistent with a flight-86 board (that is the 8255 on that board). He also claims he is reading the flight-86 documentation. So before one can say what he is developing for it is premature to suggest a development tool. Yor suggestion doesn't work well if he's not targeting 8051.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Okay should i delete my answer then ?

Answer (score 0):

**Why do you get *illegal instruction error ?***

The reason emu8086 throws *illegal instruction* is because the instruction `CLR` does not belong to 8086 instruction set in fact its the instruction of 8051 Micro-controller. This instruction is used for clearing the carry flag (Setting Carry Flag to 0) or clearing the contents of the register in 8051 Micro-controller. On the other hand clearing the carry flag in emu8086 can be done with `CLC` instruction.

**Tool for 8051 Assembly**

The Tool that you can use for 8051 assembly is ***Keil Development tool for 8051 Micro-controller*** and you can download the same from [here](http://www.keil.com/c51/) by following [these](http://binaryupdates.com/install-keil-to-program-8051/) instructions. And for tutorials on learning 8051 assembly you can watch [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mhHJV21CDjs&list=PLXus5Oy3gD22Htt2_sox71InuHy_QbCAx) videos.